# How can the cpu type be read in the linux kernel code (viz. x86, x86_64)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to detect the cpu type while the kernel is booting (viz. x86 or x86_64) so that I can do a task differently based on the cpu type. Is there a simple way to know the CPU type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [the `cpuid` instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) ?

[There is a module](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/cpuid.4.html) interfacing it, source code [is here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.c).

If interested, also have a look [here](http://freecode.com/projects/cpuid-feature-flags) or [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/cpuid_8c-source.html) or [here](https://github.com/tycho/cpuid/blob/master/cpuid.c) for other examples.

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121792/how-to-check-if-a-cpu-supports-the-sse3-instruction-set) for using `cpuid` to know if your system supports SSE.

Answer (score 2):

You can read `/proc/cpuinfo` to get cpu type