# Simple Header Library in C / C++ for Detection of CPU Features (Supported Instruction Set)

Tags: optimization, x86, 64-bit, simd, instruction-set

I'd like to create a simple function for CPU features detection.
I need it for Run Time dispatching of code paths by the CPU features.

I'd like something really simple like:

`hasSSE3()`, `hasSSE4()`, `hasAVX()`, `hasAVX2()`, etc..

It has to be portable, namely supports Windows, macOS and Linux.
Work both on AMD and Intel CPU's.

For instance, how would one implement `hasAVX()`?

**Remark**
All I care about is x86 (And only 64 Bit CPU's).

Thank You.

Comment: GNU C (at least gcc, probably also clang and ICC) has `__builtin_cpu_supports("sse4"):` and so on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758409/intrinsics-for-cpuid-like-informations.  Do you need it to be portable across different *compilers* like MSVC, as well as target platforms?

Comment: If you rephrase your question to just ask how to portably implement `hasSSE4()` and so on, without explicitly asking for a header, it would be on topic.  The answer can be a library recommendation, but the question can't be explicitly phrased as a request for one.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I would like to be also compiler portable (MSVC, ICC, GCC) yet for starter I'd be happy with ICC.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Then use `__builtin_cpu_supports`, assuming ICC does support that GNU extension.

Comment: @PeterCordes, ICC does not support that. With ICC use e.g. `_may_i_use_cpu_feature (_FEATURE_AVX))` https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523363

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this isn't really a simple task if you want it to be portable. Compilers usually have something to help you out, but the functions are all different.

MSVC has a [`__cpuid` intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex) on x86/x86_64, but of course it's not supported on ARM. TBH I'm not sure how to get CPU capabilities on MSVC targeting ARM (or any non-x86 arch).

Compilers other than MSVC *generally* masquerade as GCC, so most of them will support the [`__builtin_cpu_init`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fcpu_005finit-1)/[`__bulitin_cpu_supports`](http://index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fcpu_005fsupports-1) intrinsics.

For other compilers you may have to use inline assembly to generate a CPUID instruction and handle the results yourself. That gets you through x86/x86_64.

Things for other architectures are a bit more complicated. For ARM, the instruction to get CPU information isn't generally accessible to unprivileged code. For glibc, you can use `getauxval` with `AT_HWCAP` and/or `AT_HWCAP2`. For non-glibc Linux, you may have to parse /proc/self/auxv and/or /proc/cpuinfo.

One pretty robust solution is Google's new [cpu_features](https://github.com/google/cpu_features/) library.

If you can sacrifice some portability, there is a [cpu](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/cpu) module in [portable-snippets](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/) (which I wrote) which could help. It's not nearly as robust as cpu_features, but it's a lot easier to integrate into your project. It should work pretty much everywhere on x86/x86_64 CPUs, but ARM support is limited to glibc, and other architectures aren't yet supported.

Comment: Hi, I don't care about ARM. Only x86 and only 64 Bit CPU's.

Comment: Your offer of Google is great. But I don't understand how to itegrate it into a project as 'h' and 'c' files. What's the needed structure?

Comment: Look at CMakeLists.txt to see how the project is built. How to integrate it with your build system depends on your build system and how you want to use it.

Comment: I have the most simple C. All I wanted is to add one line of `#include ""` to an `h` file and have the functions. I'm not into building large system. Really small code to manipulate some array with some math. As you can guess, I'm not that experienced with `CMAKE` or other. I just click on build on the IDE.

Comment: Then cpu_features is probably too complicated for you. In order to support larger and more complicated codebases a build system is pretty much a requirement. Since there is no standard way to access the information you're interested in, the more portable the solution the larger and more complicated it will be. There is probably a way to integrate cpu_features into your IDE's build system, but that's a different question and the answer depends on your IDE.

Comment: As far as I know only GCC supports `__bulitin_cpu_supports` currently. With ICC use e.g. `_may_i_use_cpu_feature (_FEATURE_AVX))`. I don't know of an option for Clang.

Comment: Clang supports `__builtin_cpu_supports`. I'm pretty sure modern ICC does, too, but I can't check it right now.

Comment: ICC supports `__builtin_cpu_supports`, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/)'s library - [Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) (VCL) can do exactly that.
One should just include the `vectorclass.h` in his project and call `instrset_detect()`.

Comment: Note that VCL's license is GPL, not LGPL.  You can only use it in open-source projects compatible with the GPL.  (Or projects where you never distribute the executable to anyone who doesn't also get source, e.g. as part of the back-end of an online service.)

Comment: Also, C++-only (unusable from C).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319245/what-is-the-minimum-version-of-os-x-for-use-with-avx-avx2/38345423#38345423

Comment: Update, VCL is now Apache licensed.