# In-code instruction-set tags possible for Visual Studio 2015 C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, x86

Maybe the wrong question. Just let me know, my assumption is that code compiled with SSE flags on will crash on a CPU without SSE available...

I have a piece of FFT-code in C++ which I want to run as efficient/fast as possible, using the available instruction set and to be compiled to a DLL. Is it possible that tags/pragmas are used within the C++ code, so that I can have the same piece of code compiled for different instruction sets? Simplified pseudo code would then be:

```
void do_FFT(double *ptr)
{
    // Detect available instruction set.

    bool MMX_available = ...;
    bool SSE_available = ...;

    // Call correct function.

    if (MMX_available)
        do_FFT_MMX(ptr);
    else if (SSE_available)
        do_FFT_SSE(ptr);
    else
        do_FFT_plain(ptr);
}

[compile next function using MMX instructions]
void do_FFT_MMX(double *ptr)
{
}

[compile next function using SSE instructions]
void do_FFT_SSE(double *ptr)
{
}

[compile next function using plain x86/64 instructions]
void do_FFT_plain(double *ptr)
{
}
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to make different DLLs for each instruction set?

Comment: By the way if it's x64 code as you hint at, SSE2 is *always* supported (not by accident, but by AMD's definition)

Comment: Using different DLLs is one way to get low-overhead runtime dispatching based on CPU features like AVX / FMA.    (Note that MMX is not helpful at all for a `double` FFT; it's integer-only.  SSE is single-precision `float` only.)  Also, the last CPU to have SSE but not SSE2 is AMD Athlon-XP from about 15 years ago.  So your examples are crazy, but this still applies to modern ISA extensions like AVX and FMA which can make a big difference, especially when your data is hot in cache.

Comment: @Peter/harold: thanks for the insight, I'll look into the specifics of the different instuction set extensions. The example I gave was only to illustrate the framework I was looking for. Now that SoronelHaetir pointed out that I can set settings per file, I can easily set up something that covers code for different instruction sets. BTW, I tried to set SSE on and already had 25% better performance. Maybe just because SSE also comes with additional registers that enable the compiler to keep pointers and intermediate variables in registers instead of on the stack?

Comment: Are you building a 32-bit executable (where SSE isn't baseline in the first place)?  Or had you disabled SSE for 64-bit so your compiler was only using x87?  Build for x64 for the best FP performance.  64-bit code has twice as many XMM registers.

Comment: @Peter: I want to make 32 and 64 bit software available, and thus also have 32 and 64 bit DLLs with FFT code. Now I have 5 sources, with different compiler settings (i.e. no_extensions/SSE/SSE2/AVX/AVX2, no others are available in the compiler) and compile/link them for x86 and x64. I want to add code to check which set is available (if AVX2, then use AVX2, else if AVX.... that order) and point to the corresponding FFT code with a function pointer. Should work I guess, and I can use the same code/settings for x86 and x64 as long as the instruction set detection code works OK.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma: Do you *really* care about 32-bit without SSE2?  Very few Pentium III CPUs are still in service.

Comment: @Peter: I do not care about old systems, the software is pretty high-end for large companies. So what I find in your comment is that I can safely assume that SSE2 is always available (both x86 and x64 [Harold's comment]) and that I have to test for CPU and OS support for cases AVX and AVX2?

Comment: In that case your baseline should be at least SSE2, maybe SSE3 (but that's only a minor speedup most of the time).  SSE2 gives you SIMD and scalar for `double`-precision floats in XMM registers (`addpd` and so on), so it's a big deal.  But yes, AVX detection requires checking that the OS has enabled it.  You can do that without any system calls, though, just CPUID + check that xsave is enabled.  You probably don't need to write the CPU detection / dispatching yourself; depending on your compiler, there are probably functions to help with this.  Use them.

Comment: The MSVC compiler I use has no means for automatic detection/dispatching (Intel compiler has...), so I can do it myself. Should not be a big deal using the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121792/how-to-check-if-a-cpu-supports-the-sse3-instruction-set

I'll update my question once I get the code completed, maybe useful for others. For now many thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it as separate DLLs, just put each function in different files and set the compile flags on a per-file basis rather than for the entire project.