# How to programmatically check if fused mul add (FMA) instruction are enabled on the CPU?

Tags: c++, windows, x86, intrinsics, avx

I would like to use the FMA instrinsics instructions _mm256_fmadd_pd(a, b, c), but my code has to run on different computers with or without FMA enabled. I cannot use a compile-time flag. So I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
__m256d a, b, c, x;
bool FMA_Enabled = CheckFMA();

if (FMA_Enabled)
{
  d = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a, b, c);
}
else
{
  x = _mm256_mul_pd(a, b);
  d = _mm256_add_pd(x, c);
}
```

I cannot find a way to write the function CheckFMA(). Is there a way to do this?

My OS is Windows 10 64 bits.

EDIT: The branching will actually be outside of the function. So I don't lose performance by checking the FMA support every time.

Comment: Are you saying that increased multiplication performance outperforms branching (which otherwise is not necessary)? Have you measured this?

Comment: I will use the branching outside of the function.

Comment: So, you want your compiled binary to contain instructions that the CPU potentially doesn't even know? This feels very, very wrong.

Comment: @lisyarus No, that is not wrong. Every CPU has API for feature detection and so it doesn't have to enter invalid instructions.

Comment: My program will contain a check that will ensure that not the not supported instructions aren't executed. The thing is, I have diverse computers and I want only one program that will execute everywhere.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121792/2747962

Comment: Look at [`__cpuid` Microsoft intrinic](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=vs-2019) and check for `AVX2` and `FMA` functions.

Comment: `__builtin_cpu_supports()` for gcc.

Comment: @freakish Now that I think of it more, it starts to make sense, thank you.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica: `_mm256_fmadd_pd` only requires the AVX and FMA3 feature bits, not AVX2.  You don't want to exclude AMD Piledriver/Steamroller unnecessarily.  Technically you need to check that the OS supports AVX (as well as the CPU), but a Windows program may be able to assume non-ancient Windows.  Really you only need to check the FMA3 feature bit; it implies AVX because that's how its encoded.  (As opposed to AMD's abandoned FMA4 feature)

Comment: Related: [AVX feature detection using SIGILL versus CPU probing](//stackoverflow.com/q/44144763) and [Which versions of Windows support/require which CPU multimedia extensions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34069054) (An OS that supports AVX doesn't need to do anything special for user-space to use AVX2 and/or FMA, so checking their CPUID feature bits is sufficient)

Comment: Also, of course you wouldn't want to actually branch around 2 vs. 1 instruction  on a value that's not known at compile time.  And if using GCC or other compiler that will contract mul+add into FMA, be when you compile with FMA code-gen enabled be careful that you don't get FMA on both paths.  You probably want different whole functions with different target options/attributes.  Or in MSVC, the compiler doesn't optimize intrinsics so I think you just need /arch:AVX and you can use FMA inside functions that are only called on CPUs with FMA enabled.

Comment: @PeterCordes Of course I won't do the branching at the lowest level. I wil do it before the whole function making the computation is called. I wrote an edit to my post to precise this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used __cpuid to code my function by modifying the microsoft code. Thank you very much to all for your help.

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <array>

bool CheckFMA()
{
    std::array<int, 4> cpui;
    std::bitset<32> ECX;
    int nIds;
    bool fma;

    __cpuid(cpui.data(), 0);
    nIds = cpui[0];

    if (nIds < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    __cpuidex(cpui.data(), 1, 0);
    ECX = cpui[2];

    return ECX[12];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `cpuid` in a loop to enumerate all possible outputs.  You only need `__cpuidex(cpui.data(), 1, 0)` inside the `if(nIds_ >= 1)` for the one leaf you ever read.  It's not a huge disaster for performance, e.g. [Ice Lake only has `0x1B`](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00706E5_IceLakeY_CPUID.txt) "basic" / low-numbered CPUID leaves to enumerate.  So it's not going to make startup take extra milliseconds.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Yes, thank you. I will correct this in my post.

Comment: Don't leave the clunky version in the answer, just show the good version.  Or at *least* put it first.  Edit to create the answer you should have posted in the first place; edit history is there if anyone wants to look.

Comment: BTW, in theory (if your code could possibly run under an ancient OS) you need to check that OS support for AVX is enabled.  [Which versions of Windows support/require which CPU multimedia extensions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34069054).  The OS has to set a bit in the CPU to make them not fault.  (This avoids the failure mode of corrupted AVX upper halves on context switches on OSes that don't know about that new architectural state.)

Answer (score 1):

Which OS? Running linux you could check `/proc/cpuinfo` for e.g. fma flag

Using Windows take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo which uses `GetLogicalProcessorInformation` function

Comment: I forgot to specify the OS : it's windows 10 64 bits.

Comment: Wouldn’t using `cpuid` directly be easier (and faster) than either of those?

Comment: I think cpuid is the right approach here. Thank you very much